# как из списка словарей по одной паре ключей вывести вторую?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дан список словарей:

```
persons = [{"name": "Sam", "age": 10}, {"name": "Jackky", "age": 47}, {"name": "Mal", "age": 12}]
```

1. Напечатать имя самого молодого человека. Если возраст совпадает - напечатать все имена.

```
list_person = []
list_name = []
max_age = 200
min_len = 0
sum_start = 0
for person in persons:
    list_person.append(person["age"])
    list_name.append(person["name"])

for element in list_person:
    if element < max_age:
        max_age = element
```

Выводит возраст, но как вытащить имя, не использую импорт коллекции?

и в этой же задаче второй вопрос:
Напечатать самое длинное имя. Если длина имени совпадает - напечатать все имена.

Я написал код:

```
for len_ele in list_name:
    longest_name = len(len_ele)
    if longest_name > min_len:
        min_len = longest_name
        print(len_ele)
```

Но опять-таки выводит 2 имени разной длины, а не одно. Как это исправить(не используя import)

Comment: "Но опять-таки выводит 2 имени разной длины, а не одно."  - потому что выводится не имя минимальной длины, а все имена, которые короче предыдущего минимума. Нужно вынести принт из цикла.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Вы можете сначала сделать список пар `(имя, возраст)`:

```
names_ages = [(person["name"], person["age"]) for person in persons]
```

(получая для вашего списка `[('Sam', 10), ('Jackky', 47), ('Mal', 12)]`)

и затем применить ваши алгоритмы.

---

Или вы можете затем из этого списка сделать упорядоченные списки:

```
by_ages = sorted(names_ages, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

> ```
> [('Sam', 10), ('Mal', 12), ('Jackky', 47)]
> ```

и

```
by_name_length = sorted(names_ages, key=lambda x: len(x[0]), reverse=True)
```

> ```
> [('Jackky', 47), ('Sam', 10), ('Mal', 12)]
> ```

чтобы из них выбирать первый (или несколько первых) элементов — например так:

```
__, min_age = by_ages[0]

for name, age in by_ages:
    if age == min_age:
        print(name)
    else:
        break
```

и

```
first_name, __ = by_name_length[0]
max_length = len(first_name)

for name, __ in by_name_length:
    if len(name) == max_length:
        print(name)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 3):

Минимальный возраст и максимальную длину имени можно посчитать:

```
min_age = float('inf')
max_len = float('-inf')

for person in persons:
    if person['age'] < min_age:
        min_age = person['age']
    if len(person['name']) > max_len
        max_len = len(person['name'])
```

и сохранить в списках, например:

```
names_min_age = [p['name'] for p in persons if p['age'] == min_age]
names_max_len = [p['name'] for p in persons if len(p['name']) == max_len]
```

Для

```
persons = [
    {"name": "Sam", "age": 10}, 
    {"name": "Jackky", "age": 47}, 
    {"name": "Polly", "age": 12},
    {"name": "Jack", "age": 10},
    {"name": "Piter", "age": 13},
    {"name": "Pan", "age": 47},
    {"name": "Mal", "age": 12},
    {"name": "Jackly", "age": 42},
]
```

Выдаст:

```
>>> names_min_age
['Sam', 'Jack']
>>> names_max_len
['Jackky', 'Jackly']
```

Answer (score 2):

что мешает сделать в 2 действия - сначала определить самый юный возраст, зачем найти всех субъектов с данным возрастом

```
persons = [{"name": "Sam", "age": 10}, {"name": "Jackky", "age": 47}, {"name": "Mal", "age": 12}]

# найти самый юный возраст
age_min = persons[0]["age"]

for dictionary in persons:
    if dictionary["age"] < age_min:
        age_min = dictionary["age"]

# выделить имена соответствующие минимальному возрасту
names_min = []

for dictionary in persons:
    if dictionary["age"] == age_min:
        names_min.append(dictionary["name"])

print(age_min, names_min)
```

можно два этапа скрестить в один:

```
age_min = persons[0]["age"]
names_min = [persons[0]["name"]]

for dictionary in persons:
    if dictionary["age"] < age_min:
        age_min = dictionary["age"]
        names_min = [dictionary["name"]]
    elif dictionary["age"] == age_min:
        names_min.append(dictionary["name"])
```

т.е. как только мы находим более юного субъекта, то начинаем формировать список заново